# SwiftUI 4 List initializer not available in iOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

When creating a list, previous versions of Xcode allowed for the following on iOS:

```
List(tabs, selection: $lastTab) {tab in
…
}
```

This now gives an error:

```
'init(_:selection:rowContent:)' is unavailable in iOS
```

also true for

```
List(tabs, id:\.self, selection: $lastTab)
```

and other variations such as:

```
List(selection: $lastTab) {
   ForEach(tabs, id:\.self) {tab in 
...
}
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, but in my case, the editor gave me a "fix" option that inserted an unusual looking autocomplete for the list.

Comment: @Stoic What was that "fix"?

Comment: Apple's tutorial from 2022 is having the same error https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/defining-the-source-of-truth-using-a-custom-binding

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You probably forgot to make selection as `Optional`, ie.

```
@State private var lastTab: Int? = 0   // << here !! `Int?`

List(tabs, selection: $lastTab) {tab in
// ...
}
```

Verified with: Xcode 14b3 / iOS 16

Comment: The error message is misleading.

Comment: Be aware that this might lead to issues with `.sheet`/`.popover`! For me using an optional for the `TabView` selection always switched back to the first tab when presenting the sheet. To workaround this I’ve bridged the optional binding to a non-optional binding.

Comment: what if I need to declare the selection as non-optional in iOS ?

Comment: Nonsensically SwiftUIy, props to you for figuring this out